# aws beanstalk us-west ami needed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ami

I need to build some custom AMIs using Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk amis as a starting point (with Java and Tomcat). I know what the values are for the US, but what are they for the eu-west-1 region?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be able to answer this question myself using the command line tool "ec2-describe-images".

Using the following provides a list of AMIs of which the official US ones are present in the list (see https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1363 ):

ec2-describe-images --owner amazon --filter "architecture=x86_64" --filter "manifest-location=*ElasticBeanstalk*"

So now I run the same thing for region eu-west-1...

ec2-describe-images --region eu-west-1 --owner amazon --filter "architecture=x86_64" --filter "manifest-location=*ElasticBeanstalk*"

And I find that for eu-west-1...

32bit Amazon Linux running Tomcat 6: ami-33261d47
64bit Amazon Linux running Tomcat 6: ami-35261d41

32bit Amazon Linux running Tomcat 7: ami-37261d43
64bit Amazon Linux running Tomcat 7: ami-4b261d3f

Cheers !!!